# Data Driven Pages ExportToAI Resolution syntax?

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

I'm fairly novice with code.  I am trying to do a simple data driven pages export to .ai using arcpy.  I need the resolution down to 150 DPI. Line 4 brings up parsing errSyntax Error: Invalid Syntax.  I feel confident it takes place where I want to put in the resolution and the quality of image.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToAI(mxd, r"M:\Projects\RAN_GIS_Project_ID\!2016\8852\RAN8851_Cricket_" + str(pageNum) + ".ai",,,,150,"NORMAL")
del mxd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1): 
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToAI(mxd, r"M:\Projects\RAN_GIS_Project_ID!2016\8852\RAN8851_Cricket_" + str(pageNum) + ".ai",resolution=150,image_quality="NORMAL")
    del mxd
```

I also recommend you shorten the Folder Path and try to avoid characters like !@$%^&* in the path name.

If you don't want to use all the parameters of a arcpy function, you shouldn't leave empty commas ",", but rather enter the parameter value like I did above.